# Libgdx - Get Intersection Rectangle from Rectangle.overlap(Rectangle)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

Is there any way to know the intersection Rectangle area between two Rectangles in libgdx like the Rectangle in c# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.intersect.aspx ?

I need to get the intersection rectangle area between that two rectangles but the overlap method in libgdx only return boolean value whether two rectangles are intersect or not.
I have read Intersector class but it provides nothing to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed, LibGDX does not have this functionality built in, so I would do something like this:

```
/** Determines whether the supplied rectangles intersect and, if they do,
 *  sets the supplied {@code intersection} rectangle to the area of overlap.
 * 
 * @return whether the rectangles intersect
 */
static public boolean intersect(Rectangle rectangle1, Rectangle rectangle2, Rectangle intersection) {
    if (rectangle1.overlaps(rectangle2)) {
        intersection.x = Math.max(rectangle1.x, rectangle2.x);
        intersection.width = Math.min(rectangle1.x + rectangle1.width, rectangle2.x + rectangle2.width) - intersection.x;
        intersection.y = Math.max(rectangle1.y, rectangle2.y);
        intersection.height = Math.min(rectangle1.y + rectangle1.height, rectangle2.y + rectangle2.height) - intersection.y;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That is actually exactly what the libgdx library does. It returns true or false for intersection, but also sets the third rectangle provided, to be the intersection area of the rectangles. Don't know if the functionality was provided after the OP asked the question, but putting this here for others to find.

Comment: Yep, I added the same to libgdx not too long after providing this answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Intersector](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Intersector.html#intersectRectangles%28com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle,%20com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle,%20com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle%29) class.

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Intersector;

Intersector.intersectRectangles(rectangle1, rectangle2, intersection);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add a slight variation to the answer of nEx Software. This one will work even if you want to store the resulting value in one of the source rectangles:

```
public static boolean intersect(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2, Rectangle intersection) {
    if (!r1.overlaps(r2)) {
        return false;
    }

    float x = Math.max(r1.x, r2.x);
    float y = Math.max(r1.y, r2.y);
    float width = Math.min(r1.x + r1.width, r2.x + r2.width) - x;
    float height = Math.min(r1.y + r1.height, r2.y + r2.height) - y;
    intersection.set(x, y, width, height);

    return true;
}
```

Here is an example usege:

```
Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle();
Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle();

// ...

intersect(r1, r2, r1);
```