# Moving platform collision detection

Tags: libgdx, collision-detection

I have a moving platform at constant speed and I need to update my player position when my olayer jump ont that platform. But I have problems with collision detection. Here how I try to detect collision between my player's bottom Rectangle and platform Rectangle.

```
    for(GameObject t2 : list){
                    if(t2 instanceof Platform){

                        platform = (Platform) t2;
                        render.rect(platform.getHitBox().getX(), 
                                    platform.getHitBox().getY(),
                                    platform.getHitBox().getWidth(),
                                    platform.getHitBox().getHeight());

                        platform.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 0,
                                        player1.getHitBox().getX(), 
                                        Gdx.graphics.getWidth());

                        if(platform.getHitBox().overlaps(player1.getHitBox())
                           ||player1.getHitBox().overlaps(platform.getHitBox())){

                            System.out.println("true");

                            platformPositonX = player1.getHitBox().getX() 
                                              + platform.getUpdateSpeed();

                            player1.action2(1, platformPositonX, 
                                           (platform.getHitBox().y +
                                           platform.getHitBox().height));

                        }else{
                            System.out.println("false");
                        }
                    }
}
```

Here's my print screen and my result printed in concole [image]
As you can see my collision don't work correctly. When my character is not on the platform my result are correct I get `false`
 but when my character is on the platform i got `true`, `false`, `false`, `true`, ......

Comment: Why are you checking for collision twice? player1.getHitBox().overlaps(platform.getHitBox() and platform.getHitBox().overlaps(player1.getHitBox() are both same and would return the same result. Overlaps means they are colliding with "each other".

Comment: Now to your problem, are you sure you are updating the platform hitbox as the platform moves? Can you post the code of your Platform class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found out what's wrong. In this line I need to substract a number

```
 player1.action2(1, platformPositonX,(platform.getHitBox().y + platform.getHitBox().height - 5 ));
```

Now all works!

Answer (score 0):

into your sample code, just enter "false" println, if not overlaping, and touched is true, I do not know what is "touched" in this case, but if you want to enter only if, ovelaping is false, your pudes provar this:

in your code says:

```
..// other code

    }else if(touched){
            System.out.println("false");
    }
}
```

change for this:

```
..// other code

    }else{
            System.out.println("false");
    }
}
```

You might also be interested to look at this:

[Libgdx - Get Intersection Rectangle from Rectangle.overlap(Rectangle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267221/libgdx-get-intersection-rectangle-from-rectangle-overlaprectangle)